# Access Conditional formatting expression based on subform value (date)

Tags: ms-access

I need to set conditional formatting expression that is based on date, but date is in subform (form and subform is always in datalist view). I dont know if I must use DLookup function, or directly write field < Date().

I was try this expression, but I get syntax error "Operator missing in query expression ID=:

```
"[subform]..Forms![datefield]" < Date()
```

If I try classic expression, I get error "Access cannot find form..."

```
[Forms]![subform]![datefield] <Date()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
[Forms]![subform].Form![datefield] < Date()
```

Comment: If it displays records, it is not closed, thus does exist. Also, _subform_ is not the form but the _subform control_.